# Execute an exe file on external filename

Tags: c#, postgresql

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "C:/Users/test/AppData/Local/Temp "+ "\" C:/Program Files/test/PostgreSQL/12/bin/pg_upgrade.exe\"";

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
.....
```

I want to run an exe file on my temp folder. How can I do that?
Like that in cmd.exe:

```
C:/Users/test/AppData/Local/Temp "C:/Program Files/test/PostgreSQL/12/bin/pg_upgrade.exe"
```

Comment: What shown cmd-part is doing? That's not a valid command.

Comment: @Sinatr - I took that as meaning he cd-ed to that directory and is just showing the view in cmd. Could be misinterpreting it though, as he left out the ">"

Comment: I want to call pg_upgrade.exe on an external file.I want to this example https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/upgrade-postgresql-9-x-to-12-x-in-windows  in c#

Comment: @BrootsWaymb, probably. I've seen screenshots of code, seeing code of screenshot is unusual.